# Python If/Else Statement Assistance

Tags: python

```
def main_menu():
    print ("Three Doors Down Figurative Language Game")
    print ("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
    print ("NOTE: TO SELECT, TYPE NUMBER OF OPTION")
    print ("")
    print (" 1) Begin Game")
    print ("")
    print (" 2) Options")
    print ("")
    print ("")
    menu_selection()
def menu_selection():
    valid_answer = ["1","2"]
    user_choice = str(input("Make a choice.."))
    if user_choice in valid_answer:
        def check_valid(user_choice):
            if user_choice == 1: #Error section V
                return("You started the game.")
            else:
                user_choice != 1
                return("Credits to ____, created by ____")
                check_valid(user_choice) #Error Section ^
    else:
        print("Please use an actual entry!")
        menu_selection()


def enterText():
    print("ENTER ANSWER!")

print (main_menu())
```

Okay, so the error should be labeled. That specific if/else statment shows up as "None" and I have tried every method to fix it. One method worked for the if/else statement on the outside, but not this one.

Comment: Use `raw_input(...)` instead of `str(input(...))`

Comment: What is this statement supposed to be doing: `user_choice != 1` It does nothing by itself

Comment: You are comparing the input to an int without previously converting the input to an int. `            if user_choice == 1: #Error section V`  that will never evaluate to True.

Comment: Also,  inside your if statement, you define a function that never gets called.

Answer (score 2):

You're taking input as a string `str(input())`. Then, you're checking `if user_input == 1`; testing to see if it is an integer, even though it is a string. Instead, try converting to an integer using `int(input())`. Also, the line `user_input != 1` is unnecessary, it's just the equivalent of writing `True` in your code. Furthermore, you define a function in your `if` statement, which shouldn't be there:

```
def main_menu():
    print ("Three Doors Down Figurative Language Game")
    print ("*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
    print ("NOTE: TO SELECT, TYPE NUMBER OF OPTION")
    print ("")
    print (" 1) Begin Game")
    print ("")
    print (" 2) Options")
    print ("")
    print ("")
    menu_selection()
def menu_selection():
    valid_answer = ["1","2"]
    user_choice = int(input("Make a choice.."))
    if user_choice in valid_answer:
        if user_choice == 1:
            return("You started the game.")
        else:
            return("Credits to ____, created by ____")
            check_valid(user_choice)
    else:
        print("Please use an actual entry!")
        menu_selection()


def enterText():
    print("ENTER ANSWER!")

print (main_menu())
```